# Von neumann entropy for reduced density matrix

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, density-operator

I have reduced density matrix of the form (corresponding to 2 coupled harmonic oscillators):

$$\rho_r (x_1, x'_1)= \frac{\text{sech}(\eta ) \sqrt{\frac{m\omega  \cosh
   (\eta )}{\hbar }} \exp \left(-\frac{m\omega
   \text{sech}(\eta ) \left(\cosh ^2(\eta )
   (x_1-x_1')^2+(x_1+x_1')
   ^2\right)}{4 \hbar }\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$

Where $\eta $ is a constant. What is the easiest way to calculate von Neumann entropy for matrix like this one? I read that one can look for its eigenvalues:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d x^{\prime} \rho_{\mathrm{}}\left(x, x^{\prime}\right) f_{n}\left(x^{\prime}\right)=p_{n} f_{n}(x)
$$
But how to calculate above equation? Is there any way except guessing solution?
Thanks in advance

Edit: Groundstate wavefunction for coupled harmonic oscilltors:
$$
\psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=\left(\frac{m \omega}{\pi \hbar}\right)^{1 / 2} \exp \left(-\frac{m \omega}{4 \hbar}\left(e^{-\eta}\left(x_{1}-x_{2}\right)^{2}+e^{\eta}\left(x_{1}+x_{2}\right)^{2}\right)\right)
$$
From this I create density matrix (matrix elements):
$$
\rho\left(x_{1}, x_{2},x_{1}', x_{2}'\right)=\psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \psi^{*}\left(x_{1}', x_{2}'\right)
$$
Then I trace over $x_2$ and result is reduced densit matrix from beginning

Comment: Can you provide a bit of context?  (Note: If this is 2 harmonic oscillators, there should be a basis in which they decouple.  Also, how can this be 2 harmonic oscillators if there is only one position coordinate?)

Comment: It is reduced density matrix. I traced over degrees of freedom of second oscillator. I follow calculations from Kim et al. paper "Illustrative example of feynman rest of universe" (pdf avaible). Yes, it is possible to schmidt decompose this matrix, but it is very difficult to do this

Comment: What do you mean by "Schmidt decompose"? This is something you do for pure states, not mixed states.  It might still be easier if you write the original pure state (before tracing) as well.

Comment: Note that harmonic oscillators are very likely much easier to solve in the Fock basis - or, if everything is quadratic, then in a covariance matrix formalism.  I think what you are doing unnecessarily complicates things, which is why it might be easier if you provide some context.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. So I traced this pure state matrix and got reduced one. I just follow calculations from Kim's paper. I wonder how to get entropy without Schmidt decompose pure state (it is very difficult to do this). Also Srednicki on his paper "Entropy and area" calculated entropy, but he used above formula for eigenvalues and he guessed solutions (his pure state density matrix was a bit diffrent)

Comment: I would do it in a Fock basis (or CM formalism), it should be much easier that way.  No idea how these people do it.  (The essence: After tracing one system, you are left with a thermal state of a harmonic oscillator.  That state is diagonal in the Fock basis, so you readily get the eigenvalues.)